# Widget persists between page reloads

Tags: javascript, node.js, widget, webrtc, agora.io

I want to create a widget that people can add to their website that allows them to form a webrtc connection (audio) for now. I will probably use agora for this if that is relevant. I expect this widget to be added to every single page of the website. When the user changes page within the domain is there a way to make the audio connection persist, instead of reconnecting when the user changes page.

Comment: Simple, you cant. If the user reloads the page or switch it, your connection is lost.

Comment: Technically, you can put their website into your iframe. It will work, but you probably dont want to do this :). The best solution is to open webrtc audio/video connection in new window